# View large svg file without loading the whole file

Tags: javascript, svg

I have large svg files (10-20 MB) which I would like to display in a nice viewer that allow to zoom in and out. The problem is that the user's browser needs to download the whole file before it can be displayed.

My goal is to have something like map viewer that loads only the visible part (so it will loads quickly), and will keep updating if the user moves the map or zoom in and out. Any ideas ?

Comment: Perhaps pre-slice the svg into multiple chunks then serve several of them to the client?

Comment: As an initial step I enabled gzip for svg files, and the general size of each file decreased to ~600k which helps a lot.